# Disable eager relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

In my project I have many Eloquent models that have eager relations configured in class like this:

```
protected $with = [ 'countries', 'roles' ];
```

But sometimes I need just old plain model without any relations. Can I somehow do:

```
Model::noRelations()->all()
```

Really don't wanna use query builder nor create another class just for few occasions.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you have to set the `$with` property on your model rather than leaving it empty, you can manually override the relationships that need to be eager loaded like this:

```
Model::setEagerLoads([])->get();
```

[Link to API for `setEagerLoads`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_setEagerLoads)

Comment: Works like a charm! Exactly what I need.

Comment: How can i implement this if This Model is being referred in relation of other Model something like ModelTwo::with('modelOne')->get(); how to avoid eager loading for modelOne then ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027  
i guess this should work
ModelTwo::with(['modelOne' => function ($query) { $query->setEagerLoads([]); }]

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_setEagerLoads returns 404 @Thomas Kim

Comment: still works for laravel 9 https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_setEagerLoads

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Thomas Kim answer.

If you anyway extend Eloquent\Model class and often need to strip off relations from model, this solution might suit you well.

1. Create scope in your default model class:

   ```php
   public function scopeNoEagerLoads($query){
       return $query->setEagerLoads([]);
   }
   ```
2. For any ORM, that extends that class you will be able to:

   ```php
   User::noEagerLoads()->all()
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Just like the [issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5590) say

```
Model::without(['countries', 'roles' ])->all();
```