# How to implement setEagerLoads in the current user - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to display current user loggedin information but without relation. something I just need specific information about the user model.

I have tried this similar question [Disabled eager relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052056/disable-eager-relations)

I try above answer and end up with empty user

```
window.Goyong =
      <?php echo json_encode([
          'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
          'user' => $currUser->setEagerLoads([])
]); ?>
```

The result:

```
{
    "csrfToken": "kDc5WmebrWlHzyV77pdYZCW69kaiGK6ZC29zAvFn",
    "user": {}
}
```

How can I show current user without bringing any relation?

Comment: Did you try Auth::user() ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here:

1. `$currUser` seems to be an empty User object (try with `Auth::user()` as suggested by @Paul instead)
2. `setEagerLoads([])` doesn't make much sense once the model has already been retrieved from the database. You can, however, remove relationship using `setRelations([])`.

Example:

```php
$withEagerLoadedRelationships = Subscriber::query()->with('profiles')->first();
$withoutRelationships = $withEagerLoadedRelationships->setRelations([]);
```

Btw, unless you need those eager loaded relationships somewhere else you should act at the instantiation of `$currUser` removing the eager loading from the beginning.