# How to disable/override $with attribute in Laravel models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship, laravel-5.8

I have this model:

```
class Payment extends MyBaseModel
{  
    protected $table = 'payments';
    protected $with = ['company', 'account', 'manager', 'block', 'network'];
    protected $appends = ['someAttribute', 'someOtherAttribute'];

   ...
}
```

In another model I have a relation that looks like this:

```
public function payment() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Payment', 'payment_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
}
```

What I need is to be able to, sometimes, retrieve $this->payment without all the the relationships specified in $with (i.e. company, account, manager, block, network) also would like to (sometimes) disable the appended attributes.

Can't find a way to accomplish that. I've tried the following with no luck.

```
public function payment() {
    $this->belongsTo('App\Payment', 'payment_id', 'id')->setEagerLoads([])->withTrashed();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable eager relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052056/disable-eager-relations)

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI Can't see how I would redefine my relationship to use that answer. Please see what I tried  from your suggestion. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like below help you to dynamically disable eager loading on relationship

```
OtherModel::with(['payment'=>function($query){
    $query->setEagerLoads([]);
}])->get();
```

Comment: The thing is I really need to have it disabled right in the relationship (please see my edit)

Comment: How about using `without(['company', ...])` on `$this->belongsTo('App\Payment', 'payment_id', 'id')`

Comment: My bad, actually your first suggestion works (the answer from the other post)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to iterate over the model collection and setAppends because setAppends and hidden can't work for belongsTo or hasMany relationship. Here is my idea.

***contoller.php***

```
$exceptRelationships = ['company', 'account', 'manager', 'block', 'network'];
$setAppends = ['someAttribute'];

$payments = $anotherModelInstance->payment($exceptRelationships)->get();

// foreach on each payment and set required appends.
// if you don't want any then simply set empty array.
$payments->each(function ($payment, $key) use ($setAppends) {
        $payment->setAppends($setAppends);
        // $payment->setAppends([]);
    }
);
```

***AnotherModel.php***

```
public function payment($without = [])
{
    return $without ? $this->belongsTo('App\Payment', 'payment_id', 'id')->withTrashed()->without($without) : $this->belongsTo('App\Payment', 'payment_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
}
```